# Where can one find the exact implementation of operator new in C++?

Tags: c++, gcc, new-operator

Operator new is sometimes implemented with malloc, where could one find the exact implementation of it in an embedded systems, running say Raspbian.

Comment: For user space code, it's this: https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=tree;f=malloc;h=1103943adc88e23a879cea14b55d730d06516b11;hb=HEAD , it's the same as is running on most linux distros.

Answer (score 3):

> Where can one find the exact implementation of operator new in C++?

You'll find that in the source code of a C++ standard library. Here's the one from [libstdc++](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob_plain;f=libstdc%2B%2B-v3/libsupc%2B%2B/new_op.cc;h=1c19d4477668242eea1803b76e2638fbd699fe92;hb=HEAD):

```
_GLIBCXX_WEAK_DEFINITION void *
operator new (std::size_t sz) _GLIBCXX_THROW (std::bad_alloc)
{
  void *p;

  /* malloc (0) is unpredictable; avoid it.  */
  if (sz == 0)
    sz = 1;

  while (__builtin_expect ((p = malloc (sz)) == 0, false))
    {
      new_handler handler = std::get_new_handler ();
      if (! handler)
    _GLIBCXX_THROW_OR_ABORT(bad_alloc());
      handler ();
    }

  return p;
}
```

As you can see, it is in this case implemented with `malloc`.

> in an embedded systems

The standard libraries of embedded systems are typically *freestanding*, and therefore don't necessarily provide `malloc` or `new` at all.

> running say Raspbian.

Raspbian is a pretty much fully blown operating system. It'll use libstdc++ by default.

Comment: Rather depends what you mean by "embedded".  My guess is that if you count all the different embedded devices, you would find most are running Linux or *BSD.  (That is, count by model, not by number of individual devices).

Comment: @MartinBonner yeah, I suppose that there is no singular hard definition for "embedded". If you take a point of view where a computer embedded into a larger entity is an "embedded system" (which is completely fine definition), then question about embedded system becomes pointless from programming perspective, since there is no technical difference between embedded, and non-embedded.

Comment: Agree with Martin Bonner.   The definition of an embedded system is a essentially a computer system that provides a dedicated set of functions within a larger system.   It has nothing to do with having an operating system.   There are embedded systems with and without operating systems, and quite a few run a Linux or BSD based OS, simply because such an OS is readily available at low cost, configurable, and provides a lot of useful functionality that make it easier to integrate a system within a larger system. It's the usage of the system that makes it embedded, not hosting Raspberry Pi or not

Comment: Traditionally, “embedded” was synonym with “limited-resource”. The use of the word implied at most a few MB of memory, often a few kB or even a few bytes, lack of some basic hardware features (no FPU, no paging, …). All of that made an environment that could not support standard-compliant libc, let alone libc++. It's very common for such systems not to have `malloc` of `printf`. On the other hand they deal with non-standard stuff: interrupt vectors, direct I/O on hardware, … I guess people used to working with such systems kept that meaning of “embedded”.